# where to put primary flag in one to many relation

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I got this problem:

- User have many Candies  (**1:M**),
- one of the Candies can have flag **primary**
- only one candy per user can be primary

Which way is better solution to do primary flag?

#### solution1:

Users

```
| id  | name |
| 1   | Joe  |
```

Candies

```
| id | user_id | primary |
| 1  |  1      | true    |  
| 2  |  2      | false   |
```

#### solution2:

Users

```
| id  | name | primary_candy_id |
| 1   | Joe  | 2                |
```

Candies

```
| id | user_id |
| 1  |  1      |
| 2  |  2      |
```

---

**Notes to Soluion 1**

- I got everything related to Candy in Candies table
- faster query if I check if any Candy is primary (don't have to join)
- If  User got 100 candies, this way he have 99 of them *false* and only 1 meaningful *true* => 99 unnecessary column records

**Notes to Solution 2**

- this way I'll  have only one column record (saves 99 other)
- If I want to check if the Candy is primary, I need to do join on client table
- let say I introduce more 1:M tables with primary flag related to User: icecreams, chocolates, junkfoods,... this way I'll have 4 more columns in User

This is more SQL problem but I'm using Rails 3.* in project so best practice opinions from this field welcome

Answer (score 1):

I would create a third model called `UserCandy` or something like that, and then have the database tables look like this:

```
# users
| id | name |
| 1  | Joe  |

# candies
| id | name    |
| 1  | foo bar |

# user_candies
| id | user_id | candy_id |
| 1  | 1       | 1        |

# primary_candies
| id | user_candy_id |
| 1  | 1             |
```

I would then set up a many-to-many relationship between users and candies, since there is probably more than one person that likes `<insert some special type of candy here>`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_candies
  has_many :candies, :through => :user_candies

  def primary_candy
    Candy.primary_for(self).first
  end
end

class Candy < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_candies
  has_many :users, :through => :user_candies

  scope :primary, joins(:user_candies => [:primary_user_candy, :user])
  scope :primary_for, lambda {|user| primary.where('users.id' => user.id) }
end

class UserCandy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :candy
  has_one :primary_candy
end

class PrimaryCandy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_candy

  validate do
    if user_candy.user.primary_candy
      errors.add(:base, "User already has a primary  candy")
    end
  end
end
```

This way, you won't have to add columns to the users table when you add different types of snacks, and also, since a user might or might not have a favorite candy, you'll avoid null fields in the users table this way.

You can also reuse the different candy types this way.

So, my short answer, from a relational database perspective, would be: I wouldn't have a flag, I would put primary candy in a separate model.

That said, you could go with a three table version as well, and just put the primary flag in the user_candies table.

I made a sample rails project with the above model code, available [here](https://github.com/Frost/candy_test).

Answer (score 0):

What about a has_one association. That way you eliminate the unnecessary column in both and can easily access the User.primary_candy only when you need to.

```
User :has_many candy
User :has_one candy :through => primary_candy 

Candy :belongs_to user
Candy :has_many primary_candy

Primary_candy :belongs_to User
Primary_candy :belongs_to Candy
Primary_candy :validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :candy_id
```

user.primary_candy.candy would return the associated candy.
user.candy would return the set of all of the candies.

You could create a method in the candy model to check primary_candy and .find only that record also.

```
def p_candy(user)
  p_candy_id = Primary_candy.find_by_user_id(user.id).candy_id
  p_candy = Candy.find(p_candy_id)
  return p_candy
end
```

It also gives you easy access to see the relative popularity of different primary candies.
Just a though, GL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that people often make this unnecessarily complicated by creating an unncessary link table for a non-existent one-to-many relationship.   MyFavoriteColor is a monadic attribute of "me" ("favorite") so I would do simply this:

```
      Tables:
         PEOPLE
         COLORS
```

and People.FavoriteColor column must contain a key from the COLORS table:

```
       ALTER TABLE PEOPLE ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PEOPLE_COLOR
       foreign key(FavoriteColor) REFERENCES COLOR(id)
```

Now,  let's say you had a clothing store and you wanted to track the color(s) an item is available in (red shirt, blue shirt, green shirt) why then you WILL need a one-to-many relationship linkage table:

```
       Tables:
           APPAREL
           COLORS
           APPARELCOLORS

       T-Shirt is an item in the APPAREL table
       Red, green, blue, white, etc are items in the COLORS table


        And then you'd have this in the APPARELCOLORS linkage table:


             Apparel | Color
             t-shirt | red
             t-shirt | blue
             hat   | white
             hat | black
             hat | yellow
```

The "favorite" rule --that is, only one of the several values assopciated with an entity can have the "favorite" column set to True-- cannot be enforced DECLARATIVELY.  You should always seek to find a way to enforce the rule declaratively. When you can, you know you have a good design.